# Why is this derivative 1/3?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

My book asks me to find the derivative of:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}3$$

I'm trying to learn "the long way" apparently because we haven't learned the easy way yet, says my professor.  The book says the answer is f(prime)(x) = 1/2.

Here's what I got:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2(h+a)} - \frac{1}3 - (\frac{1}{2a} - \frac{1}{3}))}h$$
$$\frac{1}3's\space cancel$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} (\frac{\frac{1}{2(h+a)} - \frac{1}{2a}}h)*\frac{2(h+a)(2a)}{2(h+a)(2a)}$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2a-2(h+a)}{h(2)(h+a)(2a)})$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2(a-(h+a))}{h(2)(h+a)(2a)})$$
$$2's\space cancel$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a(1-(h+1))}{h(h+a)(2a)})$$
$$One \space a \space cancels$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-h}{h(h+a)(a)})$$
$$h's \space cancel$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-1}{(h+a)(a)})$$
$$take \space limit$$
$$ = \frac{-1}{2a}$$

Can you help me find where I messed up??

Comment: Your function is $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x-\dfrac{1}{3}$ or $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2x}-\dfrac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Efff....  It should be $$\frac{1}2x$$ your first one.

Comment: Well, if it was $$\frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}3 $$ is my version at least correct??

Comment: No. It would then be $-\frac1{2a^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a - (h+a)) \neq a(1 - (h+1)) $$

It is useful to resolve a problem from scratch -- especially if you can do things in different ways or in different orders (even slight differences). If you're not referring to your erroneous work, you're not likely to repeat most mistakes.

Another tool for debugging an algebraic calculation is to simply plug in numbers. If you plugged in, say, $a=2$ and $h=3$ into every rational function you're trying to simplify, you'll know you have an error when the value you get changes. (if I have a calculator, I'd use more complicated numbers: the only reason I choose $2$ and $3$ is because they're not too bad to work with by hand)

Answer (score 2):

You made four separate mistakes.

The first one occurs at the very beginning:  you set things up as the derivative of ${1\over2x}-{1\over3}$, not ${1\over2}x-{1\over3}$.

The second one occurs just below the "$2$'s cancel":  you should have been left with $a-(h+a)$, not $a(1-(h-1))$.

The third occurs just below the "One $a$ cancels":  You cancelled the $a$ in the numerator with a $2$ in the denominator.

The fourth occurs at the very end, where you take the limit:  When you let $h\to0$ in $(h+a)(a)$ in the denominator, you should get $a^2$, not $2a$.

Everything else looks good!

Comment: I feel this answer took more time to really explore the OP's post